# How to collect user input and give feedback

Tags: arrays, ruby, compare

I am struggling with my code to write a simple code-breaking game.
There is a hidden code:

```
code = ["a","b","b","c"]
```

My program asks for user input, then stores it in a variable.
I want to compare user input against the secret code variable and give the user feedback: 1 for a good letter in good place, 0 for good letter in wrong place, "-" for wrong letter.

I came up with something like this:

```
feedback = []
input.each_with_index do |v,i|
  if v == code.fetch(i)
    feedback << "1"
  else
    feedback << "-"
  end
end
```

It works OK when it compares elements at the same index. I have no idea how I can find elements that are in the code array, but not in the same index and give feedback to the user.

For example:

```
code = ["a","b","b","c"]
input = ["b","b","a","z"]
feedback = ["0","1","0","-"]
```

Comment: What should be returned for `input = ["a", "a", "a", "a"]`?

Comment: 1 - for same letter at same index, 0 - for same letter but wrong index, "-" for wrong letter:

feedback = ["1" , " - ", " - ", " - " ]

Comment: It's basically a mastermind with position information.

Comment: It's suprisingly bug prone for such a simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

This code works with the 3 examples you mentioned.

2 passes are used because the `1`s must be returned before the `0`s :

```
def give_feedback(input, code)
  feedback = Array.new(input.size) { '-' }
  code2 = code.dup

  input.each_with_index do |letter, index|
    if letter == code[index]
      feedback[index] = '1'
      code2[index]    = nil
    end
  end

  input.each_with_index do |letter, index|
    next if feedback[index] == '1'
    found = code2.index(letter)
    if found
      feedback[index]  = '0'
      code2[found]     = nil
    end
  end
  feedback
end

p give_feedback(%w(b b a z), %w(a b b c))
# ["0", "1", "0", "-"]
p give_feedback(%w(a a a a), %w(a b b c))
# ["1", "-", "-", "-"]
p give_feedback(%w(c c b a), %w(a b b c))
# ["0", "-", "1", "0"]
```

Comment: almost works, but for input = %w( c c b a), it gives wrong feedback = [0 0 1 0], and correct one should be, feedback = [ 0 , - , 1, 0]

Comment: @zensupremacy Sorry about that, there were no less than 3 bugs a single loop!

Comment: Two loops are bah :) See my sexy variant.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Always a pleasure to get your feedback :) Your "sexy" variant doesn't work for `input = %w( c c b a)`.

Comment: looks like You solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `include?` method to see if that character is in the list at a different index. Something like this:

```
input.each_with_index do |v,i|
  if v == code.fetch(i)
    feedback << "1"
  elsif code.include?(v)
    # right character, wrong spot
    feedback << "0"
  else
    feedback << "-"
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you, i will check how it works
edit: i checked and it doesn't work. in your code it will give "?" for characters that doesn't exist in code array, and it should give "-" to tell user that it is wrong letter and it is not included in code array.

Comment: The '?' is for you to figure out. Your question did not contain a spec for the expected behavior.

Comment: sorry but your code doesnt work, i knew what you mean by "?" but i have used your notation of "?" to not mess anyone else reading it.i think my spec is correct. when giving feedback 1 - for correct letter + correct index, 0 - for correct letter but wrong index, " - " for wrong letter. i think it is pretty self explanatory. but anyway thanks for trying

Comment: Sorry I had missed that the character was supposed to be '0' in your original question. I have since updated my answer and you can now run it and see that it meets your spec.

Answer (score 0):

One more solution

```
code = ["a","b","b","c"]
input = ["b","b","a","z"]

feedback = input.map.with_index do |num, ind|
  if code.include? num
    code[ind] == num ? '1' : '0'
  else
    '-'
  end
end

=> ['0', '1', '0', '-']
```

if you want define `feedback` before, just edit 1st variant to:

```
code = ["a","b","b","c"]
input = ["b","b","a","z"]
feedback = []

input.each_with_index do |num, ind|
  if code.include? num
    feedback << (code[ind] == num ? '1' : '0')
  else
    feedback << '-'
  end
end
```

result would be the same

Comment: it works ok, but it gives wrong feedback if input = ["b","b","b","b"], it gives this feedback = [0 1 1 0], and it should produce feedback = [ - , 1, 1, - ]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` and `map` to make it a little more functional. `include?` will check to see if the input is in `code`

```
code = %w(a b b c)
input = %w(b b a z)
result = code.zip(input).map do |c, i|
  if c == i
    '1'
  elsif code.include?(i)
    '0'
  else
    '-'
  end
end
puts result.to_s
```

Comment: see @mudasobwa's question in comments.

Comment: doesn't work, for input = %w( b b b b) , it produces wrong feedback = [ 0 1 1 0]. what it should produce is feedback = [ - , 1 , 1 , - ]

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity:

```
[code, input].map { |a| (0...a.size).zip(a).to_h }
             .reduce do |e, acc|
  c = acc.values.dup
  acc.merge(e) do |_, v1, v2|
    case (c.delete_at(c.index(v2)) rescue nil)
    when v1 then "1"
    when nil then "-"
    else "0"
    end
  end
end.values
```

Comment: Too few `eval`, `for loops` and `rescue Exception` for my taste.